# Display XML in html with CSS style sheet

Tags: java, html, css, xml, styles

I have seen numerous ways to display an XML file in a web page (HTML) but haven't come across one that uses a CSS style sheet.

I have an XML file that already has a CSS style sheet. When the .xml is viewed in a web browser, it displays fine with CSS.
I want to display the same XML file in a webpage (HTML), whats the best way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a separate styled XML document and you want to display it in an HTML page, you could probably use the <object> tag:

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" border="0" type="text/xml" data="yourfile.xml">
<!-- alternative content used when the inclusion fails -->
</object>
```

(Tested in FireFox only). Alternatively, an <iframe> could do a similar job.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. Although, I spent some time writing a Java script within the html to read the xml and display it- and it also works fine, though the style sheet needs to be part of the web page and increases its size a bit.